# Understanding a Testflight Crash Report (iOS / React-Native / XCode)

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight, crash-reports

I have some users testing my react-native app using TestFlight. For a couple of the users the app is crashing. It does not crash for myself and another user. TestFlight provides crash reports, however, I am unsure how to view any meaningful information about them. I have managed to open them with XCode, however, it is unclear what the actual error is. Below is a screenshot of what I am seeing:

[image]

Is there something more that I need to do to see more details of this crash report? Everything I look at seems overly cryptic. How do I decipher what the problem is?

**A portion of my crash log:**

It looks like the app crashed on `Thread 6`. Here are the pertinent parts for Thread 6:

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Triggered by Thread:  6
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: 0   CoreFoundation
> 0x193a10878 _*exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199) 1
>
> libobjc.A.dylib                   0x1a7f66c50 objc_exception_throw + 60
> (objc-exception.mm:565) 2   MyExampleApp003               0x100ad26c8
> RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:145) 3   MyExampleApp003
>
> 0x100b4f1a8 -[RCTExceptionsManager
> reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:suppressRedBox:] + 492
> (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:76) 4   MyExampleApp003
>
> 0x100b4fbe0 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1536
> (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:145) 5   CoreFoundation
>
> 0x193a158f4 **invoking*** + 148 6   CoreFoundation
> 0x1938ecdf8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 448 (NSForwarding.m:3389) 7
> CoreFoundation                    0x1938ed3cc -[NSInvocation
> invokeWithTarget:] + 80 (NSForwarding.m:3495) 8   MyExampleApp003
> 0x100b024d8 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] +
> 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584) 9   MyExampleApp003
> 0x100b0466c facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*,
> unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 244 (RCTNativeModule.mm:114) 10
> MyExampleApp003               0x100b043d0 operator() + 44
> (RCTNativeModule.mm:75) 11  MyExampleApp003               0x100b043d0
> invocation function for block in
> facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int,
> folly::dynamic&&, int) + 88 (RCTNativeModule.mm:67) 12
> libdispatch.dylib                 0x19360324c
> _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1454) 13  libdispatch.dylib                 0x193604db0 _dispatch_client_callout +
> 20 (object.m:559) 14  libdispatch.dylib               0x19360c10c
> _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548) 15  libdispatch.dylib              0x19360cc5c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408
> (queue.c:3862) 16  libdispatch.dylib              0x193616d78
> _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708 (queue.c:6601) 17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1dce28804 _pthread_wqthread + 276
> (pthread.c:2207) 18  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x1dce2f75c
> start_wqthread + 8

and

> Thread 6 name: Thread 6 Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x00000001c090f414 __pthread_kill + 8 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
> 0x00000001dce27b40 pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1388) 2
> libsystem_c.dylib                 0x000000019cd34b74 abort + 104
> (abort.c:110) 3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a806ccf8
> abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:76) 4   libc++abi.dylib
> 0x00000001a805de4c demangling_terminate_handler() + 308
> (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67) 5   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x00000001a7f66f64 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:701) 6
> libc++abi.dylib                   0x00000001a806c0e0
> std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59) 7
> libc++abi.dylib                   0x00000001a806c06c std::terminate() +
> 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88) 8   libdispatch.dylib
> 0x0000000193604dc4 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:562) 9
> libdispatch.dylib                 0x000000019360c10c
> _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548) 10  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019360cc5c
> _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408 (queue.c:3862) 11  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000193616d78 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708
> (queue.c:6601) 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001dce28804
> _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2207) 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x00000001dce2f75c start_wqthread + 8

and

> Thread 6 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
> x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
> x4: 0x000000016fab5e90   x5: 0x000000016fab6440   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000700
> x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x5cfc9b6c2f3b39f6  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000003    x12: 0x0000000000000000
> x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15:
> 0x0000000000000033    x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016fab7000
> x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006    x20:
> 0x0000000000009e13  x21: 0x000000016fab70e0  x22: 0x00000001f3188380
> x23: 0x0000000000000000    x24: 0x0000000000000114  x25:
> 0x000000016fab70e0  x26: 0x0000000281996600  x27: 0x0000000000000000
> x28: 0x0000000281996600   fp: 0x000000016fab63a0   lr:
> 0x00000001dce27b40
> sp: 0x000000016fab6380   pc: 0x00000001c090f414 cpsr: 0x40000000    esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

**Full crash log: **

Due to limits in allowable text size on SO, I am not able to post my full crash log as requested. I am therefore linking to it here: https://paste.ee/p/0uokD#2OQirRwFCrlTAzGMrq8vd90cD2ThlBXk. Should something useful in the full crashlog be useful to solving the problem I will post the pertinent details here.

**My package.json**

As per request, here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "MySuperApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

** Models and iOS versions: **

So far it seems to be crashing for everyone that is testing. It is very intermittent though and mainly seems to be crashing when audio clips are clicked on. Though it only happens every so often:

- iPhone X 14.2
- iPhone 8 13.5.1
- iPad (5th generation) 13.6.1
- iPhone 11 14.2

Comment: need more info. please post the first 100 lines of the crash report. (or the whole thing, to save a re-ask)

Comment: @mr.fixit Please see new link at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @kojow7 can you add your package.json

Comment: @MuhammadNuman I've added my package.json

Comment: @kojow7 can you confirm for me that crashing devices have 13 ios or not?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman I have added the ios versions (as well as device models) to my report.

Comment: @MuhammadNuman I have posted an additional question possibly related to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398645/intermittent-crashes-with-audio-in-react-native

Answer (score 2):

**To debug errors like this you should consider adding a crash reporter** with a full error log for both native errors and React Native errors.

One of the best crash reporters you could use is **Sentry**.

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/

With that you have also the possibility to add breadcrumbs and monitor releases.

Sentry allows integration with console.error etc and you could also send report with the errors you catch in the app.

Another option could be Firebase-crashlytics https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Answer (score 0):

In frame 2, `RTCFatal` is throwing an exception. It's not caught, that's technically why the app stops.

The picture you've pasted tells me it's something to do with `facebook::react::invokeInnex...`, which is calling `[RCTModuleMethod invok...]`

But why is the exception thrown? Open the crash log as a text file, look near the top for messages about the contents of the exception. That's how you'll get closer to understanding what's going on.

Comment: Looking at the text file it looks like it happened in Thread 6 and was possibly an "Address size fault". I am not sure what that means or where I would look in the actual code for the answer.